# Show or hide divs while in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show or hide a div when the client clicks a link.

The problem is at the moment the page content `divs` are being generated via a loop.

I'm generating a unique id for the link by pulling it from the database and assigning the `checkId` function to run with the `onclick` event.

```
<div class="anchor">
    <a id="<%= order._id %>" onclick="checkId(this.id, 'moreContent');" class="button">VIEW MORE</a>
</div> 

<div class="moreContent">
    <h1>THIS WILL BE THE DIV TO SHOW OR HIDE</h1>
</div>
```

The `checkId()` function is able to log out the correct link id.

Inside the `checkId()` function, I'm assigning the moreContent div ID's
dynamically.

```
function checkId(anchorID, showDIV) {
    var anchorID = document.getElementById(anchorID);
    var showDIV = document.getElementsByClassName(showDIV);
    for (var i = 0; i < showDIV.length; i++) {
      showDIV[i].id = "show" + (i + 1);
      console.log(showDIV);
      console.log(anchorID.id);
  }
}
```

When I log moreContent ids, I can see they are all unique and incrementing properly but basically at this point I'm at a loss.

What do I need to look into to **grab the moreContent id and relate it to the original link id** or if it's even possible with this approach.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use `class` to bind. use `$(document).on('click', 'ele')` or the equivalent in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have HTML like this:

```
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#">click</a></div>
  <div class="content">content 0</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#">click</a></div>
  <div class="content">content 1</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#">click</a></div>
  <div class="content">content 2</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#">click</a></div>
  <div class="content">content 3</div>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
(function () {
  document.body.onclick = function (event) {
    var parent = event.target.parentNode,
        next;
    event.preventDefault();

    if (parent.classList.contains('anchor')) {

      next = parent.nextSibling;
      if (next.TEXT_NODE) {
        next = next.nextSibling;
      }
      next.classList.toggle('hidden');

    }
  };
}());
```

You should be able to see a working demo here: https://jsbin.com/sifuyotulo/edit?html,js,output

P.S.: keep in mind, that there might be some issues, with older IE versions. You will have to refine it for compatibility And, if you are using jquery, you should be able to easily adjust it.

Comment: Driving me crazy... because I can understand how this should work, but getting a "Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Comment: @MRMOTOFOTO the `classList` object is one of those new features, that will probably not have good sopport everywhere: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility .. you can always write your own `hasClass()`/`toggleClass()`  or use jquery do deal with it.

Comment: I assume it has to do the content being generated in a loop because I took your code and plopped it right outside the loop and it works. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MRMOTOFOTO not really. Much more likely reason is the difference in your DOM structure. That example as tailored specifically for the given DOM.

Comment: I gave up on it for a few days, but just found a simple solution that works......basically targeting first div after id div with...                                             var showDiv = id.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

Comment: Correction.....                                                                             var showDiv = id.nextElementSibling;

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).on("click",".anchor a",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data_id=$(this).attr("data-id");
$(".content").removeClass("active");
$(".content[data-id='"+data_id+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.content {
display:none;
}
.content.active {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anchor"><a href="#"  data-id="click_0">click</a></div>
  <div class="content"  data-id="click_0">content 0</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#"  data-id="click_1">click</a></div>
  <div class="content"  data-id="click_1">content 1</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#"  data-id="click_2">click</a></div>
  <div class="content" data-id="click_2">content 2</div>
  <div class="anchor"><a href="#" data-id="click_3">click</a></div>
  <div class="content" data-id="click_3">content 3</div>
```

Comment: Answers consisting only of code are not very helpful. Please explain what this code does and how it answers the question. Also, keep in mind that your answer is not only for the OP; it's for anyone else who may find this question (and subsequently your answer) in the future. Explaining your code helps people recognize if it fits their situation or if it needs to be modified to fit their situation without having to decipher the code themselves (which is a waste of their time). See [how to answer](/help/how-to-answer) for more info on how to improve your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).